# Aggregate a data.frame without a function

Tags: r, dataframe, summarization

I have the example data frame

```
test.df<-data.frame(id=c("A","A","A","B","B","B"), time=c(1:3,1:3), x1=c(1,1,1,2,2,2), x2=c("A","A","A","B","B","B"))
```

`x1` and `x2` variables are the same within each id

I would like to aggregate the above data frame to obtain the following

```
target.df<-data.frame(id=c("A","B"), x1=c(1,2), x2=c("A","B"))
```

In a sense I wish to `aggregate` without any `FUN`. I tried with `FUN=unique` but does not seem to work. My original dataframe has 1 million rows and thousands `x1,x2....` variables of different type (character, dates etc) but are the same within each ID. This is the same as a pivot table in excel

Many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem as you state seems to be removing duplicate rows from a `data.frame` and this **does not** require any aggregation. Based on your example this is what you're after:

```
unique(test.df[c(1,3,4)])
# id x1 x2
#1  A  1  A
#4  B  2  B
```

#### EDIT:

I don't quite get as to what do you mean by:

> "I tried with `FUN=unique` but does not seem to work."

Just for the sake of explaining as to what you might have gotten with `aggregate` wrong, here, I show how one could get the same with `aggregate`:

```
test.df$x2 <- as.character(test.df$x2)
aggregate(. ~ id, FUN=unique , data = test.df[c(1,3,4)] )

#  id x1 x2
#1  A  1  A
#2  B  2  B
```

However, there is no need to use `aggregate()` here. It's terribly inefficient for this problem. You can check it out with `system.time(.)` which already gives a difference even on this data:

```
system.time(unique(test.df[c(1,3,4)]))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.001   0.000   0.001 
system.time(aggregate(. ~ id, FUN=unique , data = test.df[c(1,3,4)] ))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.004   0.000   0.004
```

Go ahead and run this on your million rows and check your results with `identical` and have a look at the run time.

From your comments I think you're confused with the behaviour of `unique`. As @mnel explains, it (`unique.data.frame)` removes all duplicate rows alone from the given `data.frame`. It works for your case because you say that `x1` and `x2` will have the same values for each `ID`. So, you *dont* have to know where in the `data.frame` `ID` is. You just have to pick 1 row for each ID.

Comment: this does not help me. I wish to aggregate per ID.

Comment: @ECII this does produce desired `target.df`

Comment: but does not answer the question. I have a million rows and thousands of IDs. I cannot know when each ID first appears in order to vectorize. I have to aggregate.

Comment: @ECII I think you'll have to explain what you want to happen when one ID (say `"A"`) has multiple `time`s, `x1`s, etc, ... preferably by changing your example.

Comment: @Frank This is a longitudinal data set in long format. Each IDs has several different variables which change values with each row/measurement (like time in the example) but also some variables which remain similar throughout the same ID like x1,x2,x3

Comment: @user1317221_G Whats the point to pass the reduced dataframe  test.df[c(1,3,4)] to aggregate?=

Comment: @ECII, that was not the answer he has proposed. That was to clarify in case you did aggregate by id with unique. The answer here is obvious: `unique(.)`. What exactly is your problem with the answer? Give us an example where this doesn't work.

Comment: @ECII because your output does not have `time` in it. You removed `time` from your target result, so did I.

Comment: @user1317221_G, probably you should mention that it's not necessary (/unwise) to use `aggregate` to this problem besides the clarification of using unique in aggregation. That the OP's question *does not* require *aggregation* should be mentioned.

Comment: OK guys I got it. I misused aggregate `aggregate(. ~ id, FUN=unique , data = test.df )` works fine. Thanks for all your efforts.

Comment: Okay, one more time, do not use aggregate for this problem. It's terribly inefficient. Check the runtime with `system.time(.)`.

Comment: OK. One more time. How do you use `unique` when you **don't know** where in the dataframe (1m rows) each ID starts?

Comment: @Arun valiant attempt, only so much one can do! I edited in as you suggested. Feel free to edit if you feel like you can make this point better.

Comment: @ECII -- read the help for `?unique.data.frame`. It produces removes all duplicate rows of the data.frame -- this is what you want.